# Me sale el error [object HTMLSpanElement]

Tags: javascript, html

Me muestra los nombre y documentos junto con fechas pero cuando presiono el botón de guardar muestra todo excepto la materia seleccionada, ¿alguien sabe cómo o por qué?

Éste es mi código:

```js
function insertartextos() {
  
  console.log("insertando textos.....");
  
  var input_cliente = document.getElementById("cliente");
  var input_cc = document.getElementById("cc");
  var input_materia = document.getElementById("materia");
  var input_fechada = document.getElementById("fechada");
  var etiqueta_nombre = document.getElementById("nombre");
  var etiqueta_documento = document.getElementById("documento");
  var etiqueta_clase = document.getElementById("clase");
  var etiqueta_fecha = document.getElementById("fecha");

  etiqueta_nombre.innerHTML = "Bienvenido " + input_cliente.value;
  etiqueta_documento.innerHTML =  "Su documento es " + input_cc.value;
  etiqueta_fecha.innerHTML = "Fecha " + input_fechada.value;

  var materiaselec = document.getElementById("materias");
  var clases = document.getElementById("clase");

  if (materias.value == "programacionA"){
    clase.innerHTML = clase;
  } else if (materias.value == "ingles"){
    clase.innerHTML = clase;
  } else if (materias.value == "diseño"){
    clase.innerHTML = clase;
  } else if (materias.value == "teoria"){
    clase.innerHTML = clase;
  } else if (materias.value == "interaccion"){
    clase.innerHTML = clase;
  } else if (materias.value == "estrategia"){
    clase.innerHTML = clase;
  } else if (materias.value == "propuesta"){
    clase.innerHTML = clase;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Registro de clase</h1>
<p>Con los datos que nos proporcione podremos mantener su informacion para ayudarle con su asistencia a clases, agradecemos su colaboracion. </p>
<h3>nombre</h3>
<input type="text" id="cliente" placeholder="escribe nombre" />
<h3>documento</h3>
<input type="number" id="cc" placeholder="escribe tu nombre "/>

<h3>clase</h3>
<select id="materias">
  <option value="programacionA">programacion avanzada</option>
  <option value="ingles">ingles 3</option>
  <option value="diseño">diseño de sistemas</option>
  <option value="teoria">teoria general de sistemas</option>
  <option value="interaccion">interaccion humano computador</option>
  <option value="estrategia">diseño de estrategia</option>
  <option value="propuesta">propuesta de investigacion </option>
</select>
<h3>fecha</h3>
<input type="date" id="fechada" placeholder="escribe tu nombre "/>
<div><button type="button" onClick="insertartextos()">Guardar</button></div>

<h1>INFORMACION</h1>

<p id="nombre"></p>
<p id="documento"></p>
<span id="clase"></span>
<p id="fecha"></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Hay varios problemas en el código, vamos a verlos, pero la idea principal es que **estás intentando asignar un objeto (de tipo HTMLSpanElement) en lugar de una cadena para el `innerHTML`**.

Cuando haces esto:

```
clase.innerHTML = clase;
```

como `clase` no es una variable definida dentro de tu código, entonces el navegador intenta encontrar un elemento con `id` "clase" que utilizará en su lugar (equivalente a `document.getElementById("clase")`, que sí existe y es un `span`:

```
<span id="clase"></span>
```

Y ahora viene la parte interesante. En el código JavaScript anterior

```
clase.innerHTML = clase;
```

lo que intenta hacer es asignar como HTML interno del elemento con ID "clase", el propio elemento con ID "clase". Como estás intentando asignar un objeto a lo que debería ser una cadena, el navegador lo que hace es que escribe el tipo del objeto: `[object HTMLSpanElement]`.

---

Si lo que quieres hacer es mostrar la materia seleccionada, entonces el problema es que no estás asignando el valor correcto. Creo que lo que buscas es algo como esto (comentado donde hago cambios):

```js
function insertartextos() {
  
  console.log("insertando textos.....");
  
  var input_cliente = document.getElementById("cliente");
  var input_cc = document.getElementById("cc");
  var input_materia = document.getElementById("materia");
  var input_fechada = document.getElementById("fechada");
  var etiqueta_nombre = document.getElementById("nombre");
  var etiqueta_documento = document.getElementById("documento");
  var etiqueta_clase = document.getElementById("clase");
  var etiqueta_fecha = document.getElementById("fecha");

  etiqueta_nombre.innerHTML = "Bienvenido " + input_cliente.value;
  etiqueta_documento.innerHTML =  "Su documento es " + input_cc.value;
  etiqueta_fecha.innerHTML = "Fecha " + input_fechada.value;

  // en materiaselec tengo el select de las materias
  var materiaselec = document.getElementById("materias");
  // en materia tengo el texto del la opción seleccionada
  var materia = materiaselec.options[materiaselec.selectedIndex].innerHTML;

  // cambio clases a clase (sería esto o cambiar todos los clase.innerHTML de abajo
  var clase = document.getElementById("clase");

  if (materias.value == "programacionA"){
    clase.innerHTML = materia;
  } else if (materias.value == "ingles"){
    clase.innerHTML = materia;
  } else if (materias.value == "diseño"){
    clase.innerHTML = materia;
  } else if (materias.value == "teoria"){
    clase.innerHTML = materia;
  } else if (materias.value == "interaccion"){
    clase.innerHTML = materia;
  } else if (materias.value == "estrategia"){
    clase.innerHTML = materia;
  } else if (materias.value == "propuesta"){
    clase.innerHTML = materia;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Registro de clase</h1>
<p>Con los datos que nos proporcione podremos mantener su informacion para ayudarle con su asistencia a clases, agradecemos su colaboracion. </p>
<h3>nombre</h3>
<input type="text" id="cliente" placeholder="escribe nombre" />
<h3>documento</h3>
<input type="number" id="cc" placeholder="escribe tu nombre "/>

<h3>clase</h3>
<select id="materias">
  <option value="programacionA">programacion avanzada</option>
  <option value="ingles">ingles 3</option>
  <option value="diseño">diseño de sistemas</option>
  <option value="teoria">teoria general de sistemas</option>
  <option value="interaccion">interaccion humano computador</option>
  <option value="estrategia">diseño de estrategia</option>
  <option value="propuesta">propuesta de investigacion </option>
</select>
<h3>fecha</h3>
<input type="date" id="fechada" placeholder="escribe tu nombre "/>
<div><button type="button" onClick="insertartextos()">Guardar</button></div>

<h1>INFORMACION</h1>

<p id="nombre"></p>
<p id="documento"></p>
<span id="clase"></span>
<p id="fecha"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```js
    function insertartextos() {
      
      console.log("insertando textos.....");
      
      var input_cliente = document.getElementById("cliente");
      var input_cc = document.getElementById("cc");
      var input_materia = document.getElementById("materia")
      var input_fechada = document.getElementById("fechada");
      var etiqueta_nombre = document.getElementById("nombre");
      var etiqueta_documento = document.getElementById("documento");
      var etiqueta_clase = document.getElementById("clase");
      var etiqueta_fecha = document.getElementById("fecha");
      // correccion
      var materiaselec = document.getElementById("materias");
      // si deseas el texto
      materiaselec = materiaselec .options[materiaselec.selectedIndex].text;
      // si deseas el value
      //materiaselec = materiaselec .options[materiaselec.selectedIndex].value;

      etiqueta_nombre.innerHTML = "Bienvenido " + input_cliente.value;
      etiqueta_documento.innerHTML =  "Su documento es " + input_cc.value;
      
      etiqueta_fecha.innerHTML = "Fecha " + input_fechada.value;

 
      var clases = document.getElementById("clase");
      clases.innerHTML = materiaselec;


    }
```

```html
    <h1>Registro de clase</h1>
    <p>Con los datos que nos proporcione podremos mantener su informacion para ayudarle con su asistencia a clases, agradecemos su colaboracion. </p>
    <h3>nombre</h3>
    <input type="text" id="cliente" placeholder="escribe nombre" />
    <h3>documento</h3>
    <input type="number" id="cc" placeholder="escribe tu nombre "/>

    <h3>clase</h3>
    <select id="materias">
      <option value="programacionA">programacion avanzada</option>
      <option value="ingles">ingles 3</option>
      <option value="diseño">diseño de sistemas</option>
      <option value="teoria">teoria general de sistemas</option>
      <option value="interaccion">interaccion humano computador</option>
      <option value="estrategia">diseño de estrategia</option>
      <option value="propuesta">propuesta de investigacion </option>
    </select>
    <h3>fecha</h3>
    <input type="date" id="fechada" placeholder="escribe tu nombre "/>
    <div><button type="button" onClick="insertartextos()">Guardar</button></div>

    <h1>INFORMACION</h1>

    <p id="nombre"></p>
    <p id="documento"></p>
    <span id="clase"></span>
    <p id="fecha"></p>
```